# Loading a URL with a WKWebView in macOS

Tags: macos, wkwebview

I've made a fresh mac app project with the following code in the ViewController.

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var loginWebView: WKWebView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.loginWebView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
        
        self.view.addSubview(loginWebView)
        
        let urlReq = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://apple.com/")!)
        
        self.loginWebView.load(urlReq)
    }
}
```

For some reason when I launch the app the web view isn't loading the website. Why is this? I've been developing on iOS for years and am just getting started with macOS.

EDIT: Update loading a local file wouldn't work either

```
self.loginWebView.loadFileURL(fileURL, allowingReadAccessTo: dirURL)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem was that I had not enabled Incoming and Outgoing Connections in my app's sandboxing settings. I discovered this by reverting to using the legacy `WebView` and then getting an error code in the console. `WKWebKit` will not print error messages making something really simple incredibly difficult and confusing!. Apple really needs to fix that

Answer (score 0):

Updated for Xcode 14:

There's a checkbox under TargetName > Signing & Capabilities > App Sandbox. It needs to be checked in order to load URLs in `WKWebView`.

[image]